# Serialising large vector<bool> using boost serialization

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-serialization

I have the following test code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

class MyObject
{
public:
    MyObject()
        : m_width(0)
        , m_height(0)
        , m_data()
    {
    }

    MyObject(int width, int height)
        : m_width(width)
        , m_height(height)
    {
        m_data.resize(m_width * m_height);
        for (std::vector<bool>::iterator iter = m_data.begin(); iter != m_data.end(); ++iter)
            *iter = 1; // This could be 1 or 0 but I'm setting it to 1 for simplicity.
    }

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        archive & m_width;
        archive & m_height;
        archive & m_data;
    }

private:
    int m_width;
    int m_height;
    std::vector<bool> m_data;
};

int main()
{
    int width = 1000;
    int height = 1000;

    MyObject original(width, height);
    std::stringstream outputStream(std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::in);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive outputArchive(outputStream, boost::archive::no_header);
    outputArchive << original;

    const std::string& originalData = outputStream.str();
    int size = originalData.size();
    char *data = new char[size];
    memcpy(&data[0], originalData.c_str(), size);

    std::string buffer;
    buffer.insert(0, &data[0], size);
    std::stringstream inputStream(buffer, std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::in);
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive inputArchive(inputStream, boost::archive::no_header);

    clock_t begin = clock();

    MyObject restore;
    inputArchive >> restore;

    clock_t end = clock();
    std::cout << "Elapsed seconds: " << double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    delete [] data;

    return 0;
}
```

On my PC:

1. when "width" and "height" = 100 ==> Elapsed seconds = 0.238
2. when "width" and "height" = 1000 ==> Elapsed seconds = 23.616

What can I do to speed things up for case 2?

Comment: Which version of boost is this? Did you compile with optimization enabled? On my system, `1000x1000` runs in 0.009s (I suspect you might be using MSVC in debug mode?)

Comment: So you're comparing width and height are both 100 with width and height both 1000. That means the second case has 100 times more data than the first and the second case has 100 times the elapsed seconds. I see no problem there.

Comment: @quamrana OP doesn't say it's not scaling predictably/linearly. OP says the second case is too slow. (That makes the first case irrelevant to the question)

Comment: @sehe: My take was that the OP thought that the first case was OK, but the second case was too slow **because there was non-linearity** (emphasis mine). I'm saying that it looks perfectly linear, so solving the speed problem for the first case will solve for the second. (Which is what you said).